# Switch Configuration of Several .Net Programs for Several Sections in a Simple Way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, configuration

We build a highly configurable .Net Client/Server application.

(Client is C#/WPF, Server is C#/WebService)

There is a single code base, but each customer has its own 'profile'.

The profile contains:

- Database/Connection string
- XML configuration of many aspects of the application
- Mail Settings (SMTP/POP3/IMAP)
- other application settings

I am aware that the .Net way to do this is the App.config/Web.config/*.exe.config file, which means we need a collection of different *.config files, basically one for each customer.

The 'profile' will be used by various sections of the company and various pieces of the software:

- Development/Bug fixing  (Visual Studio, Raw Database Viewer, Helper Applications)
- Create/Edit XML Configuration  (Editor for XML Configuration)
- Testing (.exe only)
- Support (.exe only)

We need a good (simple/straightforward/understandable/maintainable) approach to switch profiles for all sections of the company.

I have seen SO Q&A [App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)

But this works around the build process inside Visual Studio. Most sections of the company do not use Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, I imagine a solution around these several *.config files, but want to **switch** them in sync

Comment: What prevents you from doing that now?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647252/switch-configuration-of-several-net-programs-for-several-sections-in-a-simple-w

Comment: I have the very same problem at work.  What I did was apply configuration transformations during my build using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebConfigTransformRunner/).  It took some tweaking to get it to work both locally and our CI server.  Unfortunately, there is no easy solution.

Comment: @gnat Well, I got virtually nothing on StackOverfow and the question seems to fit here better anyway

Comment: if you believe that question would be better fit to other site than originally asked, you can flag it for moderator attention asking to [migrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration)

Comment: Perhaps you're not getting any answers because you haven't adequately described the problem you're having.

Comment: I would elaborate on the verb "switch". I usually avoid .config files for these things. Just use files of your own design.